# Call to action to take visitors to the payment page in the header

Tags: user-behavior, call-to-action, ordering

In the header it is common to display number of items in the cart, with a button that says something like "cart".
This button is linked to the start of the payment process. But what call of action text would  most people expect, or would work better? Something like "View Cart" or "Checkout", or any other call of action you might expect. Anyone had any experience testing different texts?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your target audience. Notice that Amazon US has "View Cart" but Amazon UK has "Your Basket" because UK users think of a shopping basket and US users think of a shopping cart (we call it a trolley not a cart).

Also note that "view cart" and "checkout" are two different actions. I may want to review my purchases, change quantities, and delete some items, or save for later, before I put in my delivery options and payment and finally check out. if I saw a check out button, I would worry that all those options were missing and that the button would take me straight to the payment page.

You need to find out what the mental model of your target audience is. Look at other e-commerce sites in your region - what do they do?